# if update.message.parse_entities(types == links_list) >>> NameError: name 'types' is not defined (Python-Telegram-Bot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

sorry for my bad English :)

i wrote a telegram bot with PTB

I want to check if there is a link in the message or not

this is my code :

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters
from telegram import MessageEntity

TOKEN = "MY TOKEN"

updater = Updater(TOKEN,use_context=True)
def test(update, context):       #<<<<
    cid = update.message.chat_id
    foo = update.message.parse_entities
    links = [MessageEntity.TEXT_LINK,MessageEntity.URL]
    print(foo.type)
    if foo(type == links):
        context.bot.delete_message(cid,update.message.message_id)

#Handlers
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,test))


#Polling
updater.start_polling()
```

I run this and I send a normal message to the robot but i get this error in terminal :

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 340, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/moein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 119, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "test.py", line 12, in test
    if foo(types == links):
NameError: name 'types' is not defined
```

What is the problem with this code?

Did I write this incorrectly?

If yes, what is the correct code?

Comment: It's a simple error. You are using variable types without actually defining it. That's why you are getting error.

Comment: How should I define it? :)

Comment: Can you write complete code so that I can understand what are you trying to do actually.

Comment: yes. I edited the code and put the full code

Comment: by the way, instead of using a text filter (messages containing text) you can also use a entity filter for links `Filters.entity(TEXT_LINK)` to only pass messages containing a link to the handler. Than you don't have to check the message in the handler ;)

Comment: and it seems that the error you posted does not fit to the code example you provided. The error is caused by the line `if foo(types == links):` and says you don't have a variable called types. In your code example this line does not exist, you use the varible `type` instead.